# Google Places Autocomplete returns a different address to what is selected

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have an issue with the Google places autocomplete where an address within the CBD is searched for and found in the auto complete results, selected from the auto complete dropdown but the full address details returned from the service are for a different address.

To replicate:

1) Visit here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

2) Type in "270 king st melbourne"

3) Select the correct value (top value in dropdown)

4) See that he address populated in the fields below is in templestowe not the melbourne CBD.

5) If you type in "270 king st melbourne 3000" and select the correct result then the fields are populated correctly.

It appears that the auto complete sees the city name (i.e. melbourne) and matches on the first instance of that address within the greater city region rather than treating the city name as a suburb per se.

Is this a bug or is there a way to refine the results such that the city is treated differently? It seems like a bug to me.